# How do I download documentation and make it accessible from the command line?

Tags: fedora, man, nmap

Recently installed nmap but I don't know how to use it. I found the documentation, but I'd rather not have to leave the command line every time I try to learn something new with it. I'm still working through a book on Linux so I apologize if this is an easy thing to do.

Comment: I recommend you to use a terminal emulator with tabs support (like `gnome-terminal`). That way you can read manpages without leaving the command line.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I'm going to install that package right now. This may be a dumb question but do I need to have a GUI to use it? I've been using fedora server edition this whole time so that I can get used to it.

Comment: CLI terminal multiplexers, like `screen` and `tmux` lets you have several terminal sessions on one login/connection. Fedora has both of those programs in the repositories.

Comment: @SidneyUpton Yes, it needs a GUI. Sorry, I assumed you had one. Though, as far as I know, you can switch tty by pressing Ctrl + Alt + (F1, F2, ..., F7).

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I was wondering why it told me permission denied when I tried to assign it to a fake user in my system. Sorry for the dumb questions I'm still pretty new to this. Thanks for your time man I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `man nmap` to read manual of nmap. If you want to read some other documentation outside of manual files, you can save the documentation as text file and `cat` or `less` it in console to read it.

Comment: @SidneyUpton Welcome to Unix/Linux.